# How do I add new applications to the "Set Default Programs" list in Windows Vista/7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, file-association

In the **Set your default programs** window, you have the ability to allow an application to open all the file types it knows how to handle by default.  I have installed several programs, but almost none of them show up.  In fact, [Mozilla Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/personal.html) and [Postbox](http://www.postbox-inc.com) are the only two aside from the built in Windows applications (Paint, Windows Media Player, etc.).  How do I add applications to this list so that I don't have to assign each file type to a specific application one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756951.aspx), only applications which make use of this feature can add to the list

> Default Programs has a new
>   infrastructure to manage per-user file
>   and protocol associations designed
>   with contentious applications in mind.
>   Applications need to register in order
>   to use the functionality of Default
>   Programs.

Comment: That really stinks.  I'm very surprised that this has been around since Vista and there are still few apps that support it.

Answer (score 8):

I've [successfully added Chromium to that list](http://ciantic.blogspot.com/2010/01/add-your-program-to-default-programs-in.html), here is how I did it:

If you want to do it to your program, just replace all that seems necessary from following regfile.

For Chromium, *replace* at least the path: `C:\\Program  Copies\\Chromium\\chrome.exe` with your chromium path, it is in *two places* at the following reg file.

Put following snippet to **somefile.reg**:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Infamous capabilities:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Chromium\Capabilities]
"ApplicationDescription"="Chromium - Beta Google Chrome"
"ApplicationIcon"="C:\\Program Copies\\Chromium\\chrome.exe,0"
"ApplicationName"="Chromium"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Chromium\Capabilities\FileAssociations]
".htm"="ChromiumURL"
".html"="ChromiumURL"
".shtml"="ChromiumURL"
".xht"="ChromiumURL"
".xhtml"="ChromiumURL"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Chromium\Capabilities\URLAssociations]
"ftp"="ChromiumURL"
"http"="ChromiumURL"
"https"="ChromiumURL"

; Register to Default Programs

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications]
"Chromium"="Software\\Chromium\\Capabilities"

; ChromiumURL HANDLER:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\ChromiumURL]
@="Chromium Document"
"FriendlyTypeName"="Chromium Document"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\ChromiumURL\shell]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\ChromiumURL\shell\open]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\ChromiumURL\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Copies\\Chromium\\chrome.exe\" -- \"%1\""
```

Then as usual with reg files, you must *double click to run* them.

Comment: Thank you so much for this post. Helped me out a lot!

Answer (score 2):

To allow Chrome to appear in the Default Programs, use regedit to check the correct file path for chrome.exe appears here...

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command`

if not, change the original executable file from whatever it was,

eg. > "GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe"

to:

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\chrome.exe" (or wherever your chrome is located).
```

Answer (score 0):

if Chrome was installed without Admin rights on windows then it will not show up the 'Set Default Programs' list, however it can be set to default (and added to the list) from Chrome by `Settings > Default Browser`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one i use to associate mainly video files with Media Player Classic (Gabest) in windows 7:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Media\Media Player Classic (Gabest)]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Media\Media Player Classic (Gabest)\Capabilities]
"ApplicationDescription"="One of the most powerful, configurable multimedia players for Windows operating system, made by a Hungarian developer known as Gabest."
"ApplicationIcon"="C:\\Program Files\\mplayerc.exe,0"
"ApplicationName"="Media Player Classic (Gabest)"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Media\Media Player Classic (Gabest)\Capabilities\FileAssociations]
".avi"="mpc.avi"
".mpg"="mpc.mpg"
".mpeg"="mpc.mpeg"
".mpe"="mpc.mpe"
".m1v"="mpc.m1v"
".m2v"="mpc.m2v"
".mpv2"="mpc.mpv2"
".mp2v"="mpc.mp2v"
".pva"="mpc.pva"
".evo"="mpc.evo"
".m2p"="mpc.m2p"
".ts"="mpc.ts"
".tp"="mpc.tp"
".trp"="mpc.trp"
".m2t"="mpc.m2t"
".m2ts"="mpc.m2ts"
".mts"="mpc.mts"
".rec"="mpc.rec"
".vob"="mpc.vob"
".ifo"="mpc.ifo"
".mkv"="mpc.mkv"
".webm"="mpc.webm"
".mp4"="mpc.mp4"
".m4v"="mpc.m4v"
".mp4v"="mpc.mp4v"
".mpv4"="mpc.mpv4"
".hdmov"="mpc.hdmov"
".mov"="mpc.mov"
".3gp"="mpc.3gp"
".3gpp"="mpc.3gpp"
".3ga"="mpc.3ga"
".3g2"="mpc.3g2"
".3gp2"="mpc.3gp2"
".flv"="mpc.flv"
".f4v"="mpc.f4v"
".ogm"="mpc.ogm"
".ogv"="mpc.ogv"
".rm"="mpc.rm"
".ram"="mpc.ram"
".rmm"="mpc.rmm"
".rt"="mpc.rt"
".rp"="mpc.rp"
".smi"="mpc.smi"
".smil"="mpc.smil"
".wmv"="mpc.wmv"
".wmp"="mpc.wmp"
".wm"="mpc.wm"
".asf"="mpc.asf"
".smk"="mpc.smk"
".bik"="mpc.bik"
".fli"="mpc.fli"
".flc"="mpc.flc"
".flic"="mpc.flic"
".dsm"="mpc.dsm"
".dsv"="mpc.dsv"
".dsa"="mpc.dsa"
".dss"="mpc.dss"
".ivf"="mpc.ivf"
".d2v"="mpc.d2v"
".swf"="mpc.swf"
".divx"="mpc.divx"
".rmvb"="mpc.rmvb"
".amv"="mpc.amv"
".dts"="mpc.dts"
".aif"="mpc.aif"
".aifc"="mpc.aifc"
".aiff"="mpc.aiff"
".alac"="mpc.alac"
".amr"="mpc.amr"
".apl"="mpc.apl"
".au"="mpc.au"
".snd"="mpc.snd"
".m4r"="mpc.m4r"
".mka"="mpc.mka"
".mpa"="mpc.mpa"
".m1a"="mpc.m1a"
".m2a"="mpc.m2a"
".ra"="mpc.ra"
".aob"="mpc.aob"
".mlp"="mpc.mlp"
".wvx"="mpc.wvx"
".wmx"="mpc.wmx"
".mpcpl"="mpc.mpcpl"
".mpls"="mpc.mpls"
".bdmv"="mpc.bdmv"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications]
"Media Player Classic (Gabest)"="SOFTWARE\\Clients\\Media\\Media Player Classic (Gabest)\\Capabilities"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\mplayerc.exe\SupportedTypes]
".avi"=""
".mpg"=""
".mpeg"=""
".mpe"=""
".m1v"=""
".m2v"=""
".mpv2"=""
".mp2v"=""
".pva"=""
".evo"=""
".m2p"=""
".ts"=""
".tp"=""
".trp"=""
".m2t"=""
".m2ts"=""
".mts"=""
".rec"=""
".vob"=""
".ifo"=""
".mkv"=""
".webm"=""
".mp4"=""
".m4v"=""
".mp4v"=""
".mpv4"=""
".hdmov"=""
".mov"=""
".3gp"=""
".3gpp"=""
".3ga"=""
".3g2"=""
".3gp2"=""
".flv"=""
".f4v"=""
".ogm"=""
".ogv"=""
".rm"=""
".ram"=""
".rmm"=""
".rt"=""
".rp"=""
".smi"=""
".smil"=""
".wmv"=""
".wmp"=""
".wm"=""
".asf"=""
".smk"=""
".bik"=""
".fli"=""
".flc"=""
".flic"=""
".dsm"=""
".dsv"=""
".dsa"=""
".dss"=""
".ivf"=""
".d2v"=""
".swf"=""
".divx"=""
".rmvb"=""
".amv"=""
".ac3"=""
".dts"=""
".aif"=""
".aifc"=""
".aiff"=""
".alac"=""
".amr"=""
".ape"=""
".apl"=""
".au"=""
".snd"=""
".cda"=""
".flac"=""
".m4a"=""
".m4b"=""
".m4r"=""
".aac"=""
".mid"=""
".midi"=""
".rmi"=""
".mka"=""
".mp3"=""
".mpa"=""
".mp2"=""
".m1a"=""
".m2a"=""
".mpc"=""
".ofr"=""
".ofs"=""
".ogg"=""
".oga"=""
".opus"=""
".ra"=""
".tak"=""
".tta"=""
".wav"=""
".wma"=""
".wv"=""
".aob"=""
".mlp"=""
".asx"=""
".m3u"=""
".m3u8"=""
".pls"=""
".wvx"=""
".wax"=""
".wmx"=""
".mpcpl"=""
".mpls"=""
".bdmv"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mpc.3g2]
@="3G2"
"EditFlags"=dword:00000000
"FriendlyTypeName"="3G2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mpc.3g2\CurVer]
@="mpc.3g2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mpc.3g2\shell]
@="open"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mpc.3g2\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mpc.3g2\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\mplayerc.exe\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mpc.3ga]
@="3GA"
"EditFlags"=dword:00000000
"FriendlyTypeName"="3GA"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mpc.3ga\CurVer]
@="mpc.3ga"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mpc.3ga\shell]
@="open"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mpc.3ga\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mpc.3ga\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\mplayerc.exe\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mpc.3gp]
@="3GP"
"EditFlags"=dword:00000000
"FriendlyTypeName"="3GP"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mpc.3gp\CurVer]
@="mpc.3gp"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mpc.3gp\shell]
@="open"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mpc.3gp\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mpc.3gp\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\mplayerc.exe\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mpc.3gp2]
@="3GP2"
"EditFlags"=dword:00000000
"FriendlyTypeName"="3GP2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mpc.3gp2\CurVer]
@="mpc.3gp2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mpc.3gp2\shell]
@="open"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mpc.3gp2\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mpc.3gp2\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\mplayerc.exe\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mpc.3gpp]
@="3GPP"
"EditFlags"=dword:00000000
"FriendlyTypeName"="3GPP"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mpc.3gpp\CurVer]
@="mpc.3gpp"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mpc.3gpp\shell]
@="open"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mpc.3gpp\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mpc.3gpp\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\mplayerc.exe\" \"%1\""
```

...................cont'd............

Full version here: http://pastebin.com/BinZdHVU

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Ciantic's answer](https://superuser.com/a/90124/364367)

> If you want to do it to your program, just replace all that seems
>   necessary from following regfile.
>
> For Chromium, replace at least the path: C:\Program 
>   Copies\Chromium\chrome.exe with your chromium path, it is in two
>   places at the following reg file.
>
> Put following snippet to somefile.reg:
>
> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> ; Infamous capabilities:
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Chromium\Capabilities]
>   "ApplicationDescription"="Chromium - Beta Google Chrome"
>   "ApplicationIcon"="C:\Program Copies\Chromium\chrome.exe,0"
>   "ApplicationName"="Chromium"
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Chromium\Capabilities\FileAssociations]
>   ".htm"="ChromiumURL" ".html"="ChromiumURL" ".shtml"="ChromiumURL"
>   ".xht"="ChromiumURL" ".xhtml"="ChromiumURL"
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Chromium\Capabilities\URLAssociations]
>   "ftp"="ChromiumURL" "http"="ChromiumURL" "https"="ChromiumURL"
>
> ; Register to Default Programs
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications]
>   "Chromium"="Software\Chromium\Capabilities"
>
> ; ChromiumURL HANDLER:
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\ChromiumURL] @="Chromium
>   Document" "FriendlyTypeName"="Chromium Document"
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\ChromiumURL\shell]
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\ChromiumURL\shell\open]
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\ChromiumURL\shell\open\command]
>   @="\"C:\Program Copies\Chromium\chrome.exe\" -- \"%1\"" Then as
>   usual with reg files, you must double click to run them.

In addition to modifiying ciantic's regfile and running it, in Windows 10, I also had to go to `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\ChromiumURL\shell\open\command]` and change the default data value to the path of my chrome.exe.  In my case, it was: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Advanced Chrome\chrome.exe`.

Once I did that it showed up as a default program and not just as options to open html and other browser files.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to complete this for SRWare Iron browser:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Infamous capabilities:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Iron\Capabilities]
"ApplicationDescription"="SRWare Iron - Beta Google Chrome"
"ApplicationIcon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SRWare Iron\\iron.exe,0"
"ApplicationName"="Iron"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Iron\Capabilities\FileAssociations]
".htm"="IronURL"
".html"="IronURL"
".shtml"="IronURL"
".xht"="IronURL"
".xhtml"="IronURL"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Iron\Capabilities\URLAssociations]
"ftp"="IronURL"
"http"="IronURL"
"https"="IronURL"

; Register to Default Programs

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications]
"Iron"="Software\\Iron\\Capabilities"

; IronURL HANDLER:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\IronURL]
@="Iron Document"
"FriendlyTypeName"="Iron Document"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\IronURL\shell]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\IronURL\shell\open]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\IronURL\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SRWare Iron\\iron.exe\" -- \"%1\""
```

Comment: This answer is same as http://superuser.com/a/90124/270195 which is just duplicating the content