# Can Windows 7 be made capable of accepting Eudora as default and call it from Excel?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding Eudora to Windows 7 “Default Application” list](https://superuser.com/questions/68579/adding-eudora-to-windows-7-default-application-list)

W7 calls Windows Live Mail when an address in Excel is clicked, no matter what thilly Administrator rigmarole is tried first. Is Windows 7 deliberately blocking Eudora, or is there some secret way to get Excel to call Eudora and NOT Windows Live Mail?

Is formatting and installing XP the ONLY solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is due to the fact that Eudora is not your default e-mail client, as seen by Windows. You simply need to change the default client from Windows Live Mail to Eudora. Also, if you do not use Windows Live Mail, simply uninstall it.

To modify your Windows default programs, I suggest reading these tutorials:

[How to Set Your Default Programs in Windows 7](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-set-your-default-programs-windows-7)

[How to Set Program Access and Computer Defaults](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-set-program-access-and-computer-defaults)