# How can I add Eudora to Windows 8 "Default Application" list

Tags: windows-8

This question was asked and answered for Windows 7, but that solution apparently does not work with Windows 8.

Here is the link to the Windows 7 solution [Adding Eudora to Windows 7 "Default Application" list](https://superuser.com/questions/68579/adding-eudora-to-windows-7-default-application-list)

The Windows 7 page does not mention which version of Eudora is being used, so that may be my problem.  I am using Eudora 5.2.

However, as mentioned in the Windows 7 solution, Eudora 5.2 does have a setting to provide a warning if Eudora is not the default email program when it is started, and I have tried unchecking and checking the setting multiple times, including while opening Eudora as administrator.  However, the warning never appears and Eudora never gives me the option to set Eudora as default.

Also, after trying the solution for Windows 7 multiple times, Windows 8's "default programs" dialog continues to not show Eudora as an option (it only shows one radio button for the default email application, "Use my current e-mail program," which is apparently the Windows Mail application).

As a result, if I click on an email link on a web page Windows Mail opens and wants me to set up an account, which I do not want to do.  Windows Mail then stays open until I use Task Manager to kill it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Wow, any particular reason why you do not want to move on and insist on using a version released [more than a decade ago](http://www.eudora.com/techsupport/kb/2350hq.html), on an OS released recently? Surely it's not *that* hard to learn how to use a new email app?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to:
  - right-click Eudora icon, Run As Administrator
  - when Eudora says "make me default email app?" click Yes OK
  - because it's running as Admin, this will now work

However, on Windows 7 and 8, there is no installed email app and so the process fails.  In 7, I worked around this by installing a recognized email app (Thunderbird or Windows Live Mail), then the above worked - but it would be nice not to have to install and uninstall an unwanted email app - that's what brought me here!