# Set default browser to be Portable Chrome on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, file-association

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add new applications to the “Set Default Programs” list in Windows Vista/7?](https://superuser.com/questions/51264/how-do-i-add-new-applications-to-the-set-default-programs-list-in-windows-vist)

I've tried to use `DefaultBrowser` but it's XP only.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://superuser.com/questions/51264/how-do-i-add-new-applications-to-the-set-default-programs-list-in-windows-vista)

> According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756951.aspx), only
>   applications which make use of this
>   feature can add to the list
>
> > Default Programs has a new
> >     infrastructure to manage per-user file
> >     and protocol associations designed
> >     with contentious applications in mind.
> >     Applications need to register in order
> >     to use the functionality of Default
> >     Programs.