# How do I set Chromium Portable as my default browser in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, chromium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set default browser to be Portable Chrome on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/123811/set-default-browser-to-be-portable-chrome-on-windows-7)

There is not an option to set it as the default browser in the browser settings (it is not the same as Chrome). It also, does not appear in Windows default programs list.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Indeed, I missed that you were using a portable version. In that case *obviously* it will not show up under Default Programs. I fail to even see the point of using a portable version if you want to associate it with numerous file types and protocols, which necessitates many changes to the registry. Are you using a portable version because you lack installation rights?

Comment: group policy...

Comment: Yeah, the intention of a portable version is that it does not alter the host OS in order to function, and that its removal doesn't impact the host OS. This is why the facility to make it default is not present.  Perhaps a better option would be to see if you can install standard chromium somewhere other than program files.