# Links won't open in Outlook

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook

About a week ago Chrome (my default browser) stopped working and I ended up reinstalling.

After that, however, links in Outlook 2007, when clicked, no longer open. Instead, I get a warning that reads: **General failure. The URL was: *URL*. Application not found**.

[image: General failure. Application not found]

I presume that there is some MIME or file type association that needs to be configured at the OS level, but I've not had any luck so far. My operating system is Windows 7.

Any ideas?

#### EDIT #1

Wayne Johnston suggested I set Chrome as my default browser, but when I go to the Set Default Programs screen in Windows 7 (via Control Panel) I do not see Chrome in the list of programs. How do I get it to show up there?

[image: Set Default Programs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the your default browser is not properly registered. You can reset it by setting your default programs. This [article](http://www.pcworld.com/article/245524/microsofts_fix_for_outlooks_general_failure_error_for_email_links.html) seems to describe the problem you are experiencing. It suggests the following.

> 1. Click Start, Control Panel.
> 2. In the Search field, type default, then click Set your default programs.
> 3. Find the browser you prefer to use--say, Google Chrome--click it, and then click Choose defaults for this program.
> 4. Check the boxes next to HTTP and HTTPS, then click Save.

In general a good way to solve a problem like this is to search for the text in the error dialog. I searched for *General failure. The URL was* and got quite a few hits. The solution above was from the first hit.

Comment: Hrm, when I open Set Default Programs I don't see Chrome. (I updated my question to reflect this.)

Comment: Well, that certainly explains the first error message you reported. If Chrome isn't in the default programs list it can't be used as the default browser. But it doesn't explain why it's not there. It looks like an installation bug. This question http://superuser.com/questions/51264/how-do-i-add-new-applications-to-the-set-default-programs-list-in-windows-vist explains how to put it there, but I think it might be simpler to uninstall then install Chrome. Sorry that's not more help.

Comment: The uninstall/reinstall dance pleased the computing gods. Thanks for your assistance.