# Windows 10 keeps changing default browser to Internet Explorer at reboot

Tags: windows-10, browser, internet-explorer, reboot

In `Windows 10 (Pro, 1511 build 10586.104)`, default web browser keeps being reset to Internet Explorer at each reboot (`settings > system > default`). No matter which other browser is set there, as admin, after reboot default browser is Internet Explorer again.

Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Pushing IE11 instead of pushing Edge?   That's weird if one assumed its all evil Microsoft's fault

Comment: I have the same problem. For me, even logging off and logging back on again resets it back to IE.

Comment: I have the same issue with 1511 and 1607. I have a suspicion it may be related to synchronizing settings between machines but can't be sure until I turn that off for a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It worked for me:

1.Right click on start > Task manager

2.Click on more details

3.Go to Details tab

4.Find explorer.exe > Right click > Click "End Process" (Do not close Task manager) 
5.Go to file > Run new task > type explorer.exe  and check create this task with administrative privileges. > OK

6.Go to start > Setting > Apps > Default Apps > Web Browser > Click on Microsoft edge > select your favorite browser.

7.Restart

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me :(

Comment: Does not work.  At reboot, again the default browser is reset to IE.  The setting change takes, and is reflected as the default.  But upon reboot, its right back to stupid outdated obsolete IE.

Comment: This was working until beginning of 2019, hence the accepted answer. I'm now running Windows Enterprise 1803 build 17134.590 and it's still working.

Comment: "check create this task with administrative privileges" there is no such option unfortunately in 2020

Comment: @BlueClouds yes, there is, but you need to launch the Task Manager with administrative privileges for the checkbox to be there.

Comment: This worked for me in Windows Version 10.0.18363 Build 18363.

Comment: Unfortunately did not work on Win 10 19044.1706

Answer (score 3):

### Turn off Internet Explorer.

Be an Administrator user or Accept administrator prompt for this to work.

Steps:

1. Search "Turn Windows features on or off" {Control Panel > Programs >
   Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off (Visible on
   Left)}
2. Disable "Internet Explorer.." from Tree

Answer (score 0):

Search for defaultassociations.xml, delete it.  You'll need admin rights on the machine.  Then go to the normal 'set default apps' menu and make your selections.  Reset and you should be all set!

Comment: No such file on the system drive (C:) for Win10.

Answer (score -1):

Click on (3) dots right corner. Go to "Settings". On far left, click on "Search Engines" then "Manage Search Engines", remove unwanted search engine. Choose your search engine on line above. McAfee seems to be my culprit.

Answer (score -2):

**Follow these steps to change a default browser back to Firefox or Chrome**

- Click the menu button and choose Options.
- In the General panel, click Make Default….
- The Windows Settings app will open with the Choose default apps screen.
- Scroll down and click the entry under Web browser. In this case, the icon will say either Microsoft Edge or Choose your default browser.
- In the Choose an app screen, click chrome or Firefox to set it as the default browser.
- Firefox or Chrome is now listed as your default browser. Close the window to save your changes.

Hope this answer helps

Comment: If I understood the question, this sounds like what the OP is doing, but the selection is being changed at reboot.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

1. Right click at Start button
2. Click Control Panel
3. In the top right, click View by
4. Click either large or small
5. Click Default Programs
6. Click Set your default programs
7. On the left side, do you see your Cyberfox? If yes, click it
8. On the right side, click "Set this program as default"
9. Click OK when done