# Windows 10 keeps changing default browser to Edge at reboot

Tags: windows-10, browser, internet-explorer, group-policy, microsoft-edge

In Windows 10 (Ent, 1803), default web browser keeps being reset from Internet Explorer to Edge at each reboot (settings > system > default). No matter which other browser is set there, as admin, after reboot default browser is Edge again.

Is there a way to prevent that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the way:

1.Right click on start -> Task manager.

2.Click on more details.

3.Go to Details tab.

4.Find explorer.exe -> Right click -> Click "End Process" (Do not close Task manager).

5.Go to file -> Run new task -> type explorer.exe and check create this task with administrative privileges-> OK.

6.Go to start -> Setting -> Apps -> Default Apps -> Web Browser -> Click on Internet Explorer.

7.Then restart the machine.

Reference: [Windows 10 keeps changing default browser to Explorer at reboot](https://superuser.com/questions/1053049/windows-10-keeps-changing-default-browser-to-explorer-at-reboot)