# windows 10, firefox can't be added as a default browser

Tags: windows-10, firefox

as of superuser rules which i can't understand, i can't answer to the question here:
[Windows 10 won't accept Firefox as the default browser](https://superuser.com/questions/950434/windows-10-wont-accept-firefox-as-the-default-browser)

so i have to make a new question about it.

answer is below.

Comment: I have closed this and merged its answer with the duplicate.