# Adding a custom program to "How do you want to open this?" Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm looking for a way to add a custom application to handle specific actions (like opening a url). There's a lot documentation on **selecting** an app to perform an action, but nothing about adding a new one, except registry hacks similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/51264/how-do-i-add-new-applications-to-the-set-default-programs-list-in-windows-vist).

However, this is highly impractical as I'm not one for adding dozens of lines to my registry without knowing what they mean without an authoritative source confirming how to properly add new program handlers to windows.

My objective in this specific situation is to use my chrome incognito shortcut from urls clicked in other applications, but I'd like to know in general how to add any program to this list.

[image: Windows 10 external program selector]

Answer (score 0):

That link you posted is not a unofficial registry hack or something. It is the "Official" way to register programs with "default programs" or "default apps", which also effects "Open with" dialog. You can verify that via MSDN

[Default Programs Registration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

That's the only way. If you want to automate it, there is a 3rd party program named "default programs editor" that will do this quickly.

I've been using Chrome (incog) and added it long back to Default Programs, but Windows 10s "Default Apps" doesn't list it as it finds two registrations pointing to the same chrome.exe. But Default Programs lists it correctly.

[image]

And the Open with dialog also (in addition) lists entries that you manually choose by clicking "**choose another app..**", and it should show the chosen application from the next time. But to pre-populate entries, Default Programs registration is the way to go.