# Unable to set other application as default application for ssh protocol

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-association

I would like to use a batch file (xxxx.bat) as a default app for `ssh://` protocol in Windows 10.

However i couldn't find the "Advance" button or something similar that allows me to choose the desired file / application as the default.

Any tips please?
Or, is there anyway for me to register my batch file as an "app"?

I've tried something similar [from microsoft KB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx), but it still gets overridden by this WinSCP application.

[image: default_protocol_screenshot]
[image: Set_Associations]

Answer (score 0):

The approach shown in article [Registering an Application to a URI Scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)) is obsolete by now.

For Windows Vista and newer, see [Registering an Application for Use with Default Programs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/default-programs#registering-an-application-for-use-with-default-programs).

See also [How do I add new applications to the "Set Default Programs" list in Windows Vista/7?](https://superuser.com/q/51264/213663)

---

Alternatively, you can configure your .bat file as a [*"Terminal client"* in WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_integration_app).

It will make WinSCP open your .bat file for the [`ssh://` URLs](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_putty#url).